# Why getNetworkCountryIso() method is returning country code without Sim Card on Samsung devices?

Tags: android

[image]In my app I am getting user Country. For this I am using getNetworkCountryIso().As it is mentioned in documentation it returns registered MMC code.I have tested getNetworkCountryIso() method with and without SIM card. Without sim card it return empty string (Tested on Motorolla droid turbo and Nexus 5).But problem is when I am trying same thing on Samsung (S3 and S4 mini) it is returning country code even though both of mentioned cell phones do not have any sim card attached.And on closely look, i found out that there are some signals on status bar and sim card slot empty error as well as mentioned in picture.My question is why samsung device showing those signals what are those supposed to be? and why getNetworkCountryIso() method returning code if there is not any sim card?

Answer (score 1):

As per Samsung developer website, (http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000082); getNetworkCountryIso() should work on Wi-Fi only devices.

Comment: I didn't find anything in the documentation you linked explaining the behavior.